# Which webserver to use for hosting socket.io-java?

Tags: java, groovy, socket.io

I am pretty new to groovy/java.
I would like to host a socket.io-java server (https://github.com/tadglines/Socket.IO-Java).

In python I used gevent (https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio) to host a similar service since it provides an efficient no-blocking io event loop.

Which container in the java world provides such event loop and is suited for the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the [pom](https://github.com/tadglines/Socket.IO-Java/blob/master/core/pom.xml)
Looks like you might want to start with [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)?

Comment: Jetty however is thread based. I hoped it would work with Netty which is event based.